# Including item type "Place" in "Thing"

Tags: schema.org, microdata

According to the documentation (http://schema.org/Thing), the item type `Thing` cannot include a `Place`.

The users will be asked to add content that does not have a specific type, therefore everything falls back to `Thing`. So, suppose the following example. This is want I would like to have, but seems to be invalid. Is there a workaround to fix it?

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">
  <span itemprop="name">Eiffel Tower</span>
  <span itemprop="description">Sample description</span>
  <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
      <span itemprop="streetAddress">Sample address</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What makes you think that this snippet is invalid? -- And what exactly do you mean with "include"?

Comment: According to the docs, a `Thing` does not have (include) a `Place` as property. Therefore I think that this snippet does not follow the correct schema.org syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example snippet is valid.

Simply nesting elements with `itemscope`/`itemtype` has no effect on the parsed Microdata. You *have* to use the `itemprop` attribute if you want to associate/relate the items.

So in your example, you have three items (`Thing`, `Place`, `PostalAddress`) which are not related in any way.

If your question is, "Has `Thing` a property which allows a value of `Place`?", the answer is no, there is no such property.

Comment: Therefore I cannot connect a "Thing" to a "Place". I must use another type that has the "Place" property, right?

Comment: @Souvlaki: … that has a property that allows a value of `Place`, yes. The candidates are [listed on `Page`](http://schema.org/Place) in the table titled "Instances of `Place` may appear as values for the following properties".

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to have the user choose what "type" of thing they are submitting and map those to schema.org types.

E.g. if you had a drop-down list on the form they use to submit listing "CD", "Event", "Place", etc. and use the value from that form field to set the value of the main itemtype.

Comment: So, do you agree that my snippet is indeed invalid and cannot find a workaround given the current schema.org implementation?

Comment: I now understand that my question was a bit unclear. I have not asked how to choose the correct type, but if I can use `Place` related to a `Thing` specifically.